# maximum number of threads running in a pc

Tags: multithreading, hardware-acceleration

How can I determine the maximum number of threads running in my pc or different pc in my current network?                                                                                                                          does it depend on only hardware or something else..plz give me some reference link and suggestion 
thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be more specific:

1.If you want to know the **maximum number of concurrently executing threads** on the hardware, there are various APIs for different languages:

- C# - `Environment.ProcessorCount`.
- Java - `Runtime.availableProcessors()`.
- C - Win32 - `GetSystemInfo`.
- C - Linux - `sysconf`.

This practically gives you the number of logical CPU cores that your system has (including intel HT "cores").

2.If you want the **maximum number of threads you can start** from an application: there is no limit, except for how much memory you have and how many threads the OS can handle before it locks up. :)

Comment: thanks.. it works for Runtime.availableProcessors()